# Avoiding Magic values

Tags: coldfusion

I have some code that only does updates

```
<cfif tags NEQ "skip">
<cfquery>
UPDATE myTable
SET tags = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_varchar" value="#arguments.tags#">
WHERE ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#arguments.ID#">
</cfquery>
```

What would be a better approach than using "skip" as a magic value? Note that blank is a valid value.

Comment: A null/blank value won't work? <cfif len(trim(tags))><!--- do query ---></cfif>

Comment: Maybe this is just sample code, but don't forget to use cfqueryparam to prevent  SQL injection!

Comment: What you have isn't necessarily bad.  The first sentence of @barnyr's answer is very relevent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on where the data is coming from. Ideally, I'd set a variable to true or false and check that. I'm guessing that in your example tags is coming from a form and that 'skip' is the value in a  for 'None of these'. You've probably got to use something as a magic value, but I'd favour using something like `__SKIP_TAGS__` which is very clear.

You could also split up your page logic, so that you process the form submission first, checking for magic values and setting up a boolean for whether to insert data from #tags#, then use the boolean later on for your check. The overall logic would be the same, but better laid out.

You might want to consider adding a bit more context to your question, like where the data is coming from, so that others can give you better advice

Comment: I am going with the __SKIP_TAG__ option because a) It is even less likely than skip to be valid, and it is searchable